# Could OpenShift deploy war on a DIY Tomcat or should I switch to OpenStack

Tags: java, git, tomcat, openshift, openstack

Well, I've been trying to deploy war files on tomcat 8 DIY that I installed, but I couldn't find any useful tutorials, they all give examples with an OpenShift Tomcat 6/7 with git clone containning src folder and pom.xml. But DIY git clone contain misc and diy folders only.

I was able to deploy ode.war Apache server and axis2 through the web browser => ManagerApp, but it doesn't work with webServices it gives me 404 error.

Besides I need to deploy a BPEL process which cannot be rendered in a war file, is there a way to deploy a folder on ode that i've just installed it contain the processes folder pretty much like webapp in tomcat

Or should I switch to OpenStack, is it more easyier especially that all of this is just for test. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You are really talking about two different technologies there, OpenShift is a PaaS, and OpenStack is a way to control large pools of compute, storage, and networking resources throughout a datacenter.

If you really want to write Web Applications using Java, try using one of the application servers like JBoss, JBoss EAP, or WildFly, instead of using a servlet container (Tomcat).